# Ordering Members in Umbraco 7 Back Office

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

We are currently utilising the Umbraco 7 membership service. Our site creates members as part of a sign-up process.

In the CMS side of Umbraco I can see that the members should be sorted into folders alphabetically, however it would appear that the Name is being used to sort. This causes issues as the Name is for example "Mr Joe Blogs" which means nearly everyone ends up in the "M" folder. We have custom properties for title, forename and surname on the member object.

How can I configure umbraco to sort in to alphabetical folders by the surname property.

Also on the members manage tab Name is displayed on the grid how can I change this to surname and forename?

**Update:**

So i've done a bit more investigation and I can see that I have the MemberListView for Umbraco 7 installed and I file called memberListView.html which has an angularjs bound template and the bit I am looking at is:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="result in listViewResultSet.items"
                        ng-class="{selected:result.selected}">

                        <td>
                            <i class="icon {{result.icon}}" ng-class="getIcon(result)"></i>
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="result.selected">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- ng-class="{inactive: entityType === 'content' && !result.published}"  - use this as a template to color based on locked/approved state -->
                            <a href="#" ng-click="editMember(result.key)" prevent-default>{{result.name}}</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{result.email}}
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <span title="{{getLockedDescription(result)}}" ng-class="getLockedIcon(result)"></span>
                            <span title="{{getSuspendedDescription(result)}}" ng-class="getSuspendedIcon(result)"></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

When I try and get my custom property off result it isn't there but looking at the JSON some standard properties are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you modify the **List View - Members** data type in the Developer section you can select the property that you would like to order the members by.  It also gives you the option to change which columns appear in the grid so you should be able to replace the Name property with Forename and Surname.

If you've managed to organise the members into alphabetical folders then you may have performed some customisation already.  As far as I know this isn't possible out of the box.

Comment: I can't seem to see the **List View - Members** data type in the list of data types. I have found that the package MemberListView for Umbraco 7 is installed though.

Comment: Ah, I think that data type was added in version 7.2.0 so perhaps it isn't available to you.  Have you seen [this page](http://24days.in/umbraco/2014/managing-members/) where the author of the package explains how to add further customisations?

Comment: Robert is right - the **List View - Members** data type will let you display custom properties, and it is a part of 7.2.0 [here is the related ticket in the tracker](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-4972). [MemberListView for v7](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/memberlistview-for-umbraco-7) does not support this. However even **List View - Members** data type won't let you sort based on custom property. Maybe you will be able to update the built-in Sort property when adding / updating the member to ensure the correct sort order.